# C Programming And Data Structure

Tags: data-structures

How can we find the closest ancestor of the two different nodes of the binary tree?

Comment: yes..and i got the idea how to do...
thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each node on the path from the left node to the root, check whether that node is on the path from the right node to the root.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   ances(struct tree *root, struct tree *p, struct tree *q)
   {
    struct tree *left, *right, *temp;

    if(root->left==p || root->right==p || root->left==q || root->right==q)
    {
     return(root);
    }
    else
    {
     left = ancestor(root->left, p, q);
     right = ancestor(root->right, p, q);

     if(left!=NULL && right!=NULL)
     {
      return(root);
     } 
     else
     {
      temp = (left != NULL) ? left : right;
      return(temp);
     }
    }

    if(root == NULL)
      return NULL;
   }
```